# Using proxychains4 with core lightning on debian 12?

Tags: bitcoind, wireguard, proxychains

first time poster, please spare me if i slaughter this...

i am attempting to use proxychains4 with core lightning in an attempt to run my node through a vps that i have set up, but i also dont want to route all of my nodes internet traffic through my VPS, i have my wireguard configuration set up between my node and the vps, and its working properly. i have my proxychains4.conf configured as well, but the issue i am running into is i am unsure of how to set up my ~/.lightning/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf file to have it be able to have my VPS interact with my node. when i run proxychains4 firefox [www.dnsleaktest.com](http://www.dnsleaktest.com) it pulls up the IP address of my VPS, no issue. when i attempt to run proxychains4 lightningd --log-level=debug it runs through but breaks saying:

Could not connect to bitcoind using bitcoin-cli. Is bitcoind running?

Make sure you have bitcoind running and that bitcoin-cli is able to connect to bitcoind.

### You can verify that your Bitcoin Core installation is ready for use by running:

but another thing that has me confused is if i don't run with the --log-level=debug, lightningd shows me:

lightningd: lightning_channeld: bad version '[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
v23.11.2

---

im a complete noob when it comes to stackoverflow and have very basic knowledge of linux systems. i can post any details needed in order to help me with this issue just wasnt sure how in depth to go, if anyone is able or knows where i can find resources for this topic and will share them i will be greatly appreciative. thank you again.

for the bitcoin-cli unable to connect to bitcoind i have tried binding my internal wireguard address to my bitcoind config file with bind-addr= internalip in return i still get the same output as listed above.

for the lightningd lightninging_channeld: bad version, i have tried rebuilding core core lightning and still the same results. i have also tried binding the internal wireguard ip to my configuration file as well with the same results. i am really just looking for resource of where i can go to learn more about this. any help is appreciated